# Friendly URL profile and about using rewrite in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have this url

```
http://example.net/test
```

but i have need

```
http://example.net/test/info
```

I have this code in my htaccess ,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))$ ./id.php?u=$1
```

how to can i used code with like a link

```
http://example.net/test/info
```

Comment: Your htacces must be only pass full request string into your "u" get param. And you must parse this string to parts and route it. For example split with "/" and "?". And you must be single access point (index.php) for all pages of site.

Comment: yes i know this link working example.net/deep but i need this link for about user example.net/deep/info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. We explain it.

Your htaccess:

```
Options All -Indexes
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Your php:

```
var_dump(explode('/', explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[0]));
```

You can use this parts for call (with router) to your routines of site. Implementations of controllers, methods, routers - many and different. I do not know what you doing. I only suggest you choose the right way.

Comment: yes u true dear, how use this code ?
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))$ ./info.php?u=$1/info`

Comment: @DevKurd you not understand how works friendly url in web applications